# address in push instruction changing after modifying exe in hex

Tags: c++, assembly, free, ida

running on windows 7, 32bit home pro

I created a very simple few line app in visual studio 2008 , compiled and linked with standard libraries in release mode into executable test.exe.

The code in c is as follows:

```
char* test = "h";
int main()
{
    _asm 
    {
        push 0xFEEDBACC;
    }
    MessageBoxA(0,test,test,0);
}
```

which results in the following machine code and corresponding assembly as viewed in VS2008 (addresses rebased below, normal starting virtual address of 0x4001000)

```
char* test = "h";
int main()
{
    _asm 
    {
        push 0xFEEDBACC;
00261000 68 CC BA ED FE   push        0FEEDBACCh 
    }
    MessageBoxA(0,test,test,0);
00261005 6A 00            push        0    
00261007 68 F4 20 26 00   push        offset string "h" (2620F4h) 
0026100C 68 F4 20 26 00   push        offset string "h" (2620F4h) 
00261011 6A 00            push        0    
00261013 FF 15 A4 20 26 00 call        dword ptr [__imp__MessageBoxA@16 (2620A4h)] 
}
```

Now instead of calling MessageBox I want instead to push another string "h" right after the push 0, so using hexedit I search for the section containing FF15A420... and overwrite it to become

```
90 68 CC BA ED FE
```

Now if I open up the executable in IDA free i see the following in my .text section:

```
.text:00401000                 push    0FEEDBACCh
.text:00401005                 push    0
.text:00401007                 push    offset unk_4020F4
.text:0040100C                 push    offset unk_4020F4
.text:00401011                 push    0FFFFFF90h
.text:00401013                 nop
.text:00401014                 push    0FEEDBACCh
.text:00401019                 retn
```

this looks good so far , i see at 0x401014 my new push statement.

Now, if I debug the exe in IDA free suddenly I see my code changes (see below) the **push 0FEEDBACC** becomes **push 0FFA4BACC** and I cant see why the first 2 bytes are changed.

```
.text:00F71000 push    0FEEDBACCh
.text:00F71005 push    0
.text:00F71007 push    offset unk_F720F4
.text:00F7100C push    offset unk_F720F4
.text:00F71011 push    0FFFFFF90h
.text:00F71013 nop
.text:00F71014 push    0FFA4BACCh  // im puzzled!
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here and why the number I am pushing on is getting modified?  I tried changing the starting physical byte of this address (suspecting some sort of alignment issue) but it didnt seem to make a difference.

Thanks,

skimon

Comment: Well, that's the hard way to find out what relocation means.  Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computer_science%29

Comment: @Hans:  I bet skimon learned it good, tho. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image base was changed too between the last two screens.

I think that it just got relocated (there used to be an address): the dword at 0x15: `A4 20 26 00` points to IAT, so after relocation its high word (bytes 0x17 0x18) will be modified by adding

0x00F7 - 0x0040 = 0x00B7 to it.

Try disabling image-base randomization (or just remove the relocations).

Comment: I see so if I had overwritten the push instructions before it (since they do not include relocated functions) then my instructions would have been ok.  And I just checked, that works.  I will also lookup how to remove the relocations .  Thanks for your help.